# Google App Engine Cannot seek video html5

Tags: java, html, google-app-engine, video

I served video using `blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, response);`

On localhost, video can be seeked. But there is execption throw

```
WARNING: IOException thrown while closing Closeable.
org.mortbay.jetty.EofException
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpGenerator.flush(HttpGenerator.java:787)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.flushResponse(HttpConnection.java:693)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$Output.close(HttpConnection.java:992)
at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.io.Closeables.close(Closeables.java:77)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.serveBlob(ServeBlobFilter.java:195)
at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:67)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:368)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:351)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:97)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:485)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:89)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:46)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:450)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:169)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.flush(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:221)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpGenerator.flush(HttpGenerator.java:721)
... 31 more
```

When I deployed to Google App Engine, I cannot seek video. 
 Here is URL to try out.
http://2.organize-fpv.appspot.com/File/Serve?key=AMIfv969ZoanlvqG5DuZvBQcYTMQwAwrXQKH7vXzm8uSqEbdF7Hsms7fXtwGnovwpPVaGSjVUrhNCnMGRpLVMtB-lcVchocEBbiez-MeDdUgElMRk1469PFF_DWig5DZs6gWc_Y9fK059XfENxrnp3F_H_-g2bTFz34x7X_A7GeOjqxvcLr408s

Comment: just playing the video in a browser I am able to use seek to jump around (both just playing the video and using a <video> element in HTML5). Have you tried the same code (running on app engine) to hit a video stored elsewhere (eg S3 or regular hosting provider) as I did notice it seemed pretty slow to serve/seek which may be the issue

Comment: I found out that the problem is my school internet. When I use other internet, I can seek also.